# redis sets use sort > sorted 4 3 2 12 11 1

Tags: redis

mac 10.13
redis 4.0.8

```
redis-cli
hset info.uesr:1 email @@@ password @@@
hset info.uesr:2 email @@@ password @@@
hset info.uesr:3 email @@@ password @@@
~~~
hset info.uesr:12 email @@@ password @@@


and sadd userList info.user:*
```

when info.user:9 in to userList

used

```
sort userList by info.user:* desc
result: 
info.user:9
info.user:8
info.user:7
info.user:6
info.user:5
~~~
info.user:1
```

but now info.user:12 in the list

use

```
sort userList by info.user:* desc
result:
info.user:9
info.user:8
info.user:7
info.user:6
~~~
info.user:12
info.user:11
info.user:10
info.user:1
```

i want 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
how to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis `SORT`s lexicographically - you'll have to pad w/ 0's (i.e. "info.user:01") if you insist on going in that direction.

Alternatively, use a Sorted Set for your `userList` and assign members' scores with the id (with the [`ZADD` command](https://redis.io/commands/zadd). Then, instead of sorting, just call `ZRANGEBYSCORE`, or in your case [`ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`](https://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore).

Comment: i changed zsets and use sort userList by score desc get *->score get *->email     result = 1)null 2)email    sort can't get score?

Comment: You don't need to sort a Sorted Set - sort by nosort.